Biblatex is not performing shorthand chicago style citations
I am working in overleaf and compiling with Pdflatex.
When citing the same work twice, it is outputting a long form citation every single time. For example:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  style=chicago-notes,
  backend=biber,
  autocite=footnote,
  useibid=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{litreview.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{shorthandintro}{}
\begin{document}

The February Revolution began as a workers' revolution.\footcite[51]{source1}

Soldiers turned on their superiors.\footcite[52]{source1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}

Here is my citation in litreview.bib:
@book{source1,
  title={The Menshevik Leaders in the Russian Revolution: Social Realities and Political Strategies},
  author={Galili, Ziva},
  isbn={9780691198064},
  series={Princeton Legacy Library},
  year={2019},
  origdate={1989},  
  publisher={Princeton University Press},
}


biblatex-chicago is a bit special in that its styles should normally not be loaded via \usepackage[style=<style name>]{biblatex}, but instead via its "wrapper package" \usepackage[<style name>]{biblatex-chicago}.
Some important options are only set automatically if you load them via the wrapper package.
The following works as expected
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes,
  backend=biber,
  autocite=footnote,
  useibid=true
]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{shorthandintro}{}
\begin{document}
The February Revolution began as a workers' revolution.\footcite[51]{sigfridsson}

Soldiers turned on their superiors.\footcite[52]{worman}

Soldiers turned on their superiors.\footcite[52]{sigfridsson}

Soldiers turned on their superiors.\footcite[52]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}



Worked perfectly, thank you.
